# I can't get for loop to work the data is loaed

Tags: javascript

I can't get this for loop to work. The json data is loaded and I can see it in an `alert()` but the for loop won't run.

```
var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
var points = data.points;

var point ,Latlng;

var str = JSON.stringify(points);
    alert( "24 points  "+ str);

for (i in points ){
    point =points(i);
    results.innerHTML +=  point.latitude+" latitude is ";
}
```

here is `my_points_list_3.php` is below the data is coming across it is a join  file.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$jsonData = file_get_contents("points_3.json");
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

Comment: Hey there. I tried to improve your question, but have no idea what you mean by "here is my_points_list_3.php is below the data is coming across it is a join file.". Could you try and rephrase it?

Answer (score 2):

Change `points(i);` to be `points[i];` The square bracket is used for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
points(i)
```

to

```
points[i]
```

in order to access the data inside the points array.

Comment: @stanmroczek If the answer was helpful, then press the green checkmark.